# How to check one hour time difference between two datetime fields?

Tags: sql, datetime, hive, hiveql

I have a Hive query and I want to check that the difference between `next_datetime` and `curr_datetime` is not more than one hour.

If I add this AND clause, then it checks that both datetimes are of the same hour.

```
<...> and hour(next_datetime) = hour(curr_datetime)
```

Is there any time difference expression in minutes? It's important that `next_datetime` and `curr_datetime` might belong to different dates.

Comment: I'm not near a computer. You might want to try `... and next_datetime - curr_datetime <= interval '1' hour`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `unix_timestamp`, and check the time difference is less then 3600 secs.

```
<...> and (unix_timestamp(next_datetime) - unix_timestamp(curr_datetime) <= 3600)
```